# How do I model data that needs to maintain FIFO logic and preserve insertion order?

Tags: cassandra

the requirement I'm trying to meet is to have a Cassandra table with a prefix dimensioning (max 100k entries) and order the records with a a FIFO logic maintaining the insert order.
I'm using Cassandra for a geo-redundancy system.  I want to save event data, and the fields to include are: site-id (id of the originating site), event-type(an enum), timestamp (timestamp of the event), content (generic content of the event.

It is possible? I'm searching for a solution that prevents the tombstone problems also.

BR

Comment: https://www.datastax.com/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-datasets

Comment: 100% What Alexey said above. Another alternative to consider is to have a date based clustering column with `ASC` sort and in your read path, query it by `LIMIT 1` and process the record with some status update (or) other techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the limited details, it very much sounds like you want to store queue-like datasets which are an anti-pattern in Cassandra.

Queue data are problematic because it involves deleting records after they have been processed. Depending on how you model the data, it almost always means that the items in the front of the queue are deleted and you need to iterate over the deleted items to get to the "live" items.

As you are already aware, this leads to the "tombstone overwhelm" issue that can cripple the performance of the cluster. Cheers!